# Como baixar um projeto do bitbucket por git

Tags: git, bitbucket

Bom dia!

Nunca tinha utilizado git nem bitbucket, queria saber como faço um check out de um projeto que está no bitbucket.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: normalmente, `git clone remote-url-do-repo` e depois `git checkout master`; Mas esta informação vem, normalmente, no repositório que estás a querer clonar..

Comment: @MoshMage, já fiz o git clone, como faço o checkout? Me retorna o seguinte `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Comment: faz `cd nome-da-pasta` e depois sim, `git checkout master`

Comment: @MoshMage, perdão. Sou novo nessa área e não consegui compreender, tens como fazer uma resposta explicando? Assim também poderia receber ela como aceita.

Answer (score 2):

Como fazer git-clone de um projecto:

`git clone remote-url-do-repo`
`cd nome-do-projecto`
`git fetch`
`git checkout master`

---

O Primeiro passo faz a clonagem do projecto para a tua maquina, para dentro de uma pasta com o nome do projecto, a partir da pasta onde estás. Ou seja: Se estiveres em `/home/username/` e o projecto se chamar `xpto` esse comando irá criar a pasta `xpto` dentro da pasta `/home/username/`.

O segundo comando serve para entrares dentro da pasta (`cd` = Change Directory) que acabas-te de clonar.

O terceiro comando (`fetch`) serve para o git ir buscar todos os branches, etc, etc, etc.. que existem.

O ultimo comando faz com que tu faças `checkout` para o branch `master`